# UISplitViewController default object for Detail view controller on rotation

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller, screen-rotation

My app has a UISplitViewController with a UITableViewController as the master view, which segues to a Detail view controller. This works fine in normal operation. But I run into trouble on devices that transition from collapsed view in portrait mode to split view in landscape mode (like the iPhone X). If the user is viewing the master table view in portrait mode then there is no object selected for the Detail yet. If the device is rotated in this state, the Detail VC is forcibly displayed without any object to show.

Since no segue is invoked, how I can capture the rotation event or otherwise ensure that my Master VC passes an object to the Detail VC for display, or set it to nil if there is no object available?

My fetched results controller resides in the Master VC. Once the (empty) Detail VC starts to display, ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear are called and I can detect that there is no object for it to display. This isn’t a good place to look back to the fetched results controller to get a default object (like whatever is at IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)). It’s also possible that there is no data in the table yet, so maybe the simplest solution is to make the Detail VC nil. But once I’m detecting the problem in ViewDidLoad, it’s too late to make the Detail VC not exist.

I tried setting the UISplitViewControllerDelegate to self in the Master VC so that I could use this protocol function to detect the rotation:

```
  func splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, willChangeTo displayMode: UISplitViewController.DisplayMode) {
    print("Split view delegate notified! Will change to \(displayMode)")
}
```

But this function doesn’t get called when the device is rotated. I also tried putting this function in AppDelegate, which is already a UISplitViewControllerDelegate. In that case I can see that it is called on startup of the app but it is NOT called on user rotation of the device.

Comment: Its probably overkill and hopefully someone has a simpler solution, but you could use your UIViewController's viewWillTransition(to:with:) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition